# How to trap the 413 error in Play Framework?

Tags: java, playframework

I want to return a JSON response instead of HTML. 
I dont know how to trap it. 
For example i set the 'play.http.parser.maxMemoryBuffer' to 1MB, and if the request body will exceed 1 MB, it will return a JSON response but not HTML format saying that it is a bad response.

Comment: Here is tutorial for you: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/JavaHome

Comment: i already read the sources you've commented above but specifically my problem is that i set the play.http.parser.maxMemoryBuffer to 1MB(and that is fixed), how will i going to solve it except setting the maxMemoryBuffer higher than 1MB.... :(

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/JavaErrorHandling):
To switch from HTML to JSON response you can add this line to application.conf

```
play.http.errorHandler = play.http.JsonHttpErrorHandler
```

If you also want to customize the message, you should instead add this line to application.conf

```
play.http.errorHandler = "com.example.ErrorHandler"
```

Obviously, the line above, should point to your own implementation of the error handler, that could look like this:

```
package com.example

import play.http.HttpErrorHandler;
import play.mvc.*;
import play.mvc.Http.*;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage;
import javax.inject.Singleton;

@Singleton
public class ErrorHandler implements HttpErrorHandler {
  public CompletionStage<Result> onClientError(RequestHeader request, int statusCode, String message) {
    if (statusCode == 413) {
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(Results.status(statusCode, "A client error occurred: " + message + " The payload size should be lower than 1Mb."));
    } else {
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(Results.status(statusCode, "A client error occurred: " + message));
    }
  }

  public CompletionStage<Result> onServerError(RequestHeader request, Throwable exception) {
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(
        Results.internalServerError("A server error occurred: " + exception.getMessage()));
  }
}
```